# Re-ordering bullet list with jquery based on ahref urls

Tags: jquery

I have a UL which is dynamically fetched from the WP backend. Example markup below.

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="/parent1/">Parent 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/parent1_child1/">Parent 1Child 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/parent2/">Parent 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/parent1_child2/">Parent 1 Child 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/parent2_child2/">Parent 2 Child 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/parent2_child1/">Parent 2 Child 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

The names are examples - they are dynamic so I don't know them as a reference.

What I want to do is to order the `<li>`'s so they sit in heirachy order, so the children of the parents follow - currently the list is unordered.

I was hoping to be able to use the `a href` url as the way of doing this - becuase all children have a `parent_` at the start of their url - so wanted to add a class to the `<li>` to indicate it was a child, then hoping to match the first characters of the urls to place the children after the parent in the list...

So, the list would then become:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="/parent1/">Parent 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/parent1_child1/">Parent 1Child 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/parent1_child2/">Parent 1 Child 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/parent2/">Parent 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/parent2_child1/">Parent 2 Child 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/parent2_child2/">Parent 2 Child 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help me achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: To clarify the URLs, do the parents actually contain the string `parent<number>_`, or is it more like `<parent name>_<child name>`? (And can we assume there are no other `_` in the URL?)

Comment: No, the numbers here are just to make it easier to understand. The url of the parent is the same as the li content, then the child's url starts with the parent string.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/fyan05de/ You might have to change it a bit depending on your actual href values

Comment: looks like it might be! I will give it a go at implementing into my side and let you know if it works - thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to add a class to the child <li> elemenets as well?

Comment: Assuming your href's are always "parent_child" - ie only child `li`s have `_` then: `$("a[href*='_']").addClass("child")`  https://jsfiddle.net/tsy0qnL4/  Otherwise you need `.nextUntil()` with a match on the *prefix* of the url.

Comment: Thanks - can the class be added to the <li> rather than the <a> though?

Comment: Don't worry - I've got it to work using some additional buts I've dropped in

Comment: Just add `closest`: `$("a[href*='_']").closest("li").addClass("child")`  (or .parent()), both work across collections.

Comment: @freedomn-m Why do you answer just in the comments and not in a post?

Comment: @biberman In *this* case, I was adding to the comment from Carsten.  If I answered copying their fiddle/comment, that would be rude, would it not?

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are right...